# Apache James: mail server How To

Tags: open-source, java-11, mail-server, centos8, apache-james

I'm really struggling in the installation of Apache James 3 on CentOS 8 Stream.

I'd like to have a mail server with GUI for administration and webmail. Is Apache James right for this? I've seen that there is a binary version which seems not to have it, instead it has it if you download and build the source code, do you confirm this?

Probably I'm not understanding the documentation but I hope there's someone patience to make it clear for me.

Hoping not to make a duplicate and to hear from someone soon.

Thanks in advance

I tried to download the binary Spring Wiring and start it -> okay but it hasn't the GUI

I'd like to use the binary so I'm asking if there's a binary who ha GUI.

Comment: You can try something like mailcow, not James.